# Como transmitir dados de forma segura?

Tags: segurança, criptografia

Estou desenvolvendo dois sistemas embarcados, um supervisor e um agente. O supervisor trata-se de uma placa capaz de efetuar conexões com a Internet por meio de GPRS. Ele recebe requisições de um usuário, por meio de uma página Web, e o servidor transmite dados através de sockets de rede até o sistema embarcado. Mais tarde eu envio determinadas informações da placa aos dispositivos periféricos por meio de radiofrequência.

## **O problema**

Se essa transmissão for feita de forma simples, qualquer pessoa pode desenvolver um hardware semelhante e ver o que está sendo trafegado. Pensando nisto, utilizei o algoritmo AES para encriptar os dados. Mas de qualquer forma, se alguém repetir estes dados (mesmo encriptados) poderá ser capaz de ligar dispositivos, abrir portas e etc. Pois os dados são enviados de forma binária, conforma a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma solução temporária que encontrei, foi concatenar um conjunto de caracteres no final do pacote. Dessa forma, mesmo que o "pacote enviado" seja o mesmo, quando estes dados forem encriptados passarão a ser diferentes por conta desta string. Já no agente, salvo estas últimas strings recebidas para que mesmo se alguém repetir os dados, não ocorra nenhuma tomada de decisão (eu ignoro pacotes repetidos).

Reconheço que essa solução é muito, muito ruim. Então pesquisando um pouco, descobri que existe "sincronização por tempo usando timestamp". Mas não entendo este conceito de forma profunda. Consiste apenas em adicionar uma referência de tempo no pacote de forma que, mesmo que ele seja repetido o pacote se torna inválido? É possível fazer essa comunicação segura sem usar timestamp? Pergunto isto por uma questão de custo, já que para cada dispositivo periférico precisarei de um hardware especial, um Relógio de Tempo Real (Real Time Clock), semelhante ao da figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minhas dúvidas são:

1. O que é sincronização por tempo (timestamp)?
2. Como transmitir dados de forma segura?
3. De que forma poderia solucionar este problema de segurança na minha aplicação?

**Note que não peço exemplos de código.** Apenas gostaria de saber o que devo fazer para tornar este processo seguro.

Comment: Se ninguém responder, você pode postar a pergunta aqui: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Uma solução temporária que encontrei, foi concatenar um conjunto de caracteres no final do pacote." Apenas para referência (pois como você mesmo disse, essa solução é ruim), se o atacante obtiver o CT `X` e ele criar o CT `X xor 0000...1` então o plaintext será o mesmo, só com o último bit invertido. Isso vale tanto pro modo CBC quanto pro CTR, e possivelmente outros. Então a solução de colocar sufixos "diferentes" não impede um replay, pois é fácil construir um CT distinto do interceptado que contenha a mesma mensagem "útil" mas com um sufixo ligeiramente diferente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entenda que criptografia é um assunto denso que exige bastante estudo. Vou tentar aqui responder de forma sucinta suas perguntas.

**1 - O que é sincronização por tempo?**

Na verdade essa é uma das maneiras de sincronização utilizando um elemento variável chamado "nonce". Quando se encripta uma mensagem, a mesma sempre terá o mesmo resultado. Isso permite várias formadas de ataques à mesma, já que mensagens transmitidas nunca devem ser iguais, mesmo que forem da mesma origem. Para se evitar isso usa-se um elemento, o "nonce", que nada mais é do que um valor variável adicionado ao elemento criptografado. Dessa maneira, a mesma entidade gera mensagens diferentes que são trafegadas. O receptor deve saber o "nonce" utilizado e uma das maneiras de se gerar valores variáveis é lançando-se mão de timestamp, uma medida que sempre muda. Note que, para que o receptor decifre a mensagem ele precisa do "nonce" que pode ser enviado de forma decriptada.

Perceba que ao invés de utilizar timestamp você poderia usar um contador, que é incrementado dos dois lados, tanto da entidade que envia quanto da que recebe a mensagem encriptada.

**2 - Como transimtir os dados de forma segura?**

Na parte do circuito que envia o sinal, você cria um "nonce" de timestamp, encripta o: "nonce" + mensagem usando seu algortimo AES e envia o timestamp + mensagem encriptada com nonce + mensagem. Seu receptor, conhece o "nonce" pois o mesmo fora enviado e pode decriptar a mensagem.

**3 - De que forma poderia solucionar este problema de segurança na minha aplicação?**

Basta seguir o passo 2.

Note que ao, invés de utilizar timestamp, você poderia utilizar um contador que incrementa igualmente dos dois lados. Esse contador seria seu "nonce" e esse não precisaria ser transmitido.

Veja [esse artigo](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html) que explica bem a questão de "nonce" utilizando contadores e timestamp.

Já [essa resposta](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/what-is-the-main-difference-between-a-key-an-iv-and-a-nonce) do crypto Stack Exchange explica bem a diferença entre chave, IV e "nonce".

Comment: +1 Obrigado pela resposta. Não havia pensado na possibilidade de usar um contador. Essa ideia é brilhante, de tão simples. Sem falar que isto economizaria o hardware desnecessário do relógio em cada dispositivo. Pensarei mais nas implicações de usar um contador antes de dar a resposta como certa.

Comment: Caso tenha mais perguntas, por favor, as faça :)

Comment: Por que você sugeriu fazer `encripta o: "nonce" + mensagem usando seu algortimo AES e envia o timestamp + mensagem encriptada com nonce + mensagem"` não poderia apenas enviar `mensagem + nonce` encriptados?

Comment: Caso você utilize o timestamp, no lado que recebe a mensagem, como saber exatamente qual timestamp utilizar já que passaram-se alguns segundos? Por isso o mesmo deve ser enviado com a mensagem. Note que ele não precisa ser encriptado. Veja o artigo a seguir que fala da utilização de contadores e timestamp como "nonce": http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html

Comment: Compreendido. E quanto a chave do AES? Posso utilizar uma chave fixa visto que ela vai estar dentro do firmware?

Comment: Sim, a chave pode ser fixa!!

Comment: Obrigado pela referência. Já ia te pedir uma :P

Comment: Bem, acho que isso resolve o meu problema. Um simples contador vai gerar uma economia de um circuito `RTC` em cada dispositivo! Não havia pensado nessa possibilidade. Estava a usar uma string aleatória no final do pacote, mas isso não me era muito bom, pois não era sequencial e tinha que salvá-la no dispositivo final. Muito grato, sua solução foi brilhante. =)

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado :)

Comment: Isso que você está sugerindo (encriptar com um nonce), junto com a referência passada, trata-se simplesmente do [modo de operação CTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) (também chamado de "Counter Mode"). O CTR é um bom modo, mas sozinho ele só é seguro contra ataques passivos (*eavesdropping*). Ataques ativos (*tampering*) exigem uma proteção adicional, seja um [modo de operação autenticado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) como o CCM ou o uso de um [MAC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autenticador_de_mensagem).

Comment: P.S. 'Esse contador seria seu "nonce" e esse não precisaria ser transmitido' O modo usual de implementar o "nonce Counter Mode" é usar um nonce de 64 bits (aleatório, transmitido sim junto com a mensagem) e um contador de 64 bits, iniciado do zero e incrementado a cada **bloco** (não a cada mensagem), e juntos esses dois valores servirem de IV para o CTR. Em linhas gerais sua resposta é boa, mas é preciso cuidado pra não confundir aquilo que é necessário para proteger uma única mensagem (o IV/nonce) daquilo que é necessário pra proteger um *conjunto de mensagens*).

Answer (score 4):

> O que é sincronização por tempo (timestamp)?

Eu não tenho certeza se estamos pensando no mesmo conceito, mas uma técnica que utiliza o relógio para reforçar a segurança é a "Senha de Uso Único baseada no Tempo" ([Time-based One-Time Password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) - TOTP). Eu menciono essa técnica em [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33316/215) à minha própria pergunta sobre [Autenticação em Dois Fatores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32559/215). É o mesmo método que o Google, Facebook etc usam no seu sistema de login, em que o dispositivo móvel do usuário gera um código diferente a cada 30 segundos, e esse código tem de ser fornecido junto com a senha para autenticar-se em um computador desconhecido.

Ela não é difícil de implementar, não, na realidade é bem simples (com [14 linhas de Python](http://www.brool.com/index.php/using-google-authenticator-for-your-website) tornei meus sites/sistemas compatíveis com o [Google Authenticator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator)). A ideia geral é a seguinte:

- Um dos participantes cria uma chave secreta, e comunica essa chave ao outro participante de forma segura (no seu caso, as chaves podem ser estabelecidas na instalação).
- Quando um participante quer se autenticar com o outro, ele deriva um valor a partir dessa chave e da hora atual, truncada segundo um intervalo mínimo de tempo (no caso do Google Authenticator, o código é válido por 30 segundos).

  - Essa derivação é simplesmente um [HMAC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) (Um código ["Autenticador de Mensagem"](http://Autenticador%20de%20mensagem) - MAC - baseado em Hash) da hora atual [truncada] usando aquela chave comum como chave.
- O recipiente pega a hora local (também truncada) e refaz a derivação do código, comparando os resultados. Se forem iguais, aceita, caso contrário rejeita. É comum se testar códigos 30 segundos no passado e no futuro também, para o caso dos relógios estarem um pouco dessincronizados (isso aumenta um pouco a "janela de ataque", para 1 minuto e 30 segundos).

O interessante desse método é que mesmo que o código seja enviado em texto plano, e um atacante consiga interceptar esse código, ele só é válido por 30 segundos e depois é inútil. Não interessa quantos códigos distintos o atacante veja, ele não é capaz de descobrir qual o código esperado numa interação futura.

No seu caso, você pode usar um intervalo menor que 30 segundos, rejeitar duas ou mais mensagens num intervalo muito curto de tempo, re-sincronizar os relógios caso eles estejam defasados, etc. Cada caso é um caso. Mas só isso **não** garante que a segurança dos dados, pois:

> Como transmitir dados de forma segura?

Isso depende do que você chama de "segura", mas vou concentrar em duas propriedades (disclaimer: as únicas que [estudei até agora](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto) rsrs): confidencialidade e integridade/autenticidade (ok, são três propriedades, mas dois modos de atingi-las).

A confidencialidade normalmente se obtém encriptando os dados. Uma criptografia "perfeita" (*Perfect Secrecy*) só é conseguida se cada chave for usada uma única vez de depois descartada, **e** só se essa chave for tão ou mais longa que a mensagem cifrada (ver [*One-Time Pad*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)). Isso não é nada prático, mas felizmente existe uma noção mais relaxada de segurança, chamada "segurança semântica", que é satisfeita se a chance do adversário quebrá-la for "negligível".

Cifras de Bloco como o [AES](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43492/215) oferecem essa segurança semântica caso a mensagem seja menor ou igual ao tamanho do bloco (128 bits, ou 16 bytes) e se você *nunca* cifrar a mesma mensagem duas vezes usando a mesma chave. Já os [Modos de Operação](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_de_opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_%28criptografia%29) permitem que mensagens maiores que um bloco sejam cifradas, e o uso de alguma "randomização" (como o Vetor de Inicialização do modo CBC ou o nonce do modo CTR) permite que mais de uma mensagem seja encriptada com a mesma chave, inclusive mensagens iguais (que pela randomização gerará cifras diferentes cada vez que forem cifradas).

O problema é que a encriptação, simplesmente, só protege contra ataques passivos (*eavesdropping*) - em que o atacante lê mas não altera a comunicação. Ataques ativos (*tampering*) onde o atacante pode alterar o que é enviado entre os participantes, incluindo decidir quais mensagens vão e quais "se perdem no caminho" são capazes de burlar a criptografia, mesmo quando o algoritmo utilizado é eficaz ao proporcionar confidencialidade (ver [*Chosen Ciphertext Attack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50712/215)).

A autenticidade e a integridade normalmente se obtém usando um MAC, já citado anteriormente. De posse de uma chave comum entre o remetente e o destinatário, o remetente gera uma sequência relativamente curta de bytes (uns 80 bits ou mais devem ser suficientes) - chamada *tag* - a partir dessa mensagem, e envia essa *tag* junto à mensagem, para que o destinatário re-compute o valor e compare com a *tag* recebida. Se forem iguais, pode-se assumir que a mensagem é legítima (nota: isso *ainda não protege* contra *replays*).

Para se conquistar as três propriedades, é necessário portanto usar ambas as técnicas: encriptação e MAC. Caso decida fazê-lo em etapas separadas, sempre encripte primeiro e aplique o MAC ao *ciphertext*, isso até onde eu sei é seguro sempre (usar o MAC primeiro e encriptar tudo depois é inseguro em alguns casos, e encriptar só a mensagem e enviar o MAC *da mensagem* sem encriptar é inseguro quase sempre).

Há também a opção de se usar um modo de [Encriptação Autenticada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption), como o OCB (aviso: patentes!), EAX, GCM e [CCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode). Esse último é particularmente interessante pro seu caso, pois a mesma primitiva criptográfica usada para encriptar (o AES) também é usada para criar o MAC - de modo que a quantidade total de código a ser utilizada fica reduzida. Você também pode usar esse método para implementar o TOTP (caso venha utilizá-lo), poupando-o de incluir uma implementação do SHA caso você já não esteja usando isso.

> De que forma poderia solucionar este problema de segurança na minha aplicação?

Ok, *replays*. Bom, eu tenho pouco conhecimento do assunto, mas vou descrever exatamente o que sei sobre o protocolo [TLS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (1.2), que resolve essa questão de uma maneira que - acredito eu - seja satisfatória (se não for, acho que não tem um único site seguro no mundo rsrs):

O TLS usa 4 chaves simétricas em cada sessão ([as chaves são estabelecidas durante o protocolo de "aperto-de-mão"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28828/215), e são efêmeras, mas nada impede que você use chaves fixas - você só perde a [*perfect forward secrecy*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50833/215), mas isso provavelmente não é importante no seu caso). Uma pra "Alice" encriptar para "Bob", outra pra Alice assinar, outra pra Bob encriptar para Alice e a última para Bob assinar (nota: por "assinar" eu me refiro a aplicar o MAC).

Cada mensagem trocada possui um cabeçalho e um corpo. O cabeçalho não é encriptado (vai em texto plano), mas é autenticado (entra na geração do MAC). Além disso, ambos os lados mantém um par de contadores, representando quantas mensagens (no caso, pacotes) foram enviadas de um lado pro outro.

O ponto-chave aqui é que na hora de gerar o MAC se utiliza a mensagem em si (lembrete: não faça isso - encripte primeiro depois crie o MAC; no caso particular do TLS é seguro, mas é muito fácil cometer um erro se você fizer dessa forma), os dados do cabeçalho, **e o contador** representando aquela mensagem. De modo que o MAC gerado só vale para aquele contador, se o atacante reenviar o pacote em um momento futuro, a verificação do MAC falhará, pois nesse momento o contador já terá mudado.

No TLS o contador é implícito (ambas as partes sabem qual é o contador, ele não é enviado junto da mensagem), e se ocorrer um erro - qualquer erro - na hora de decriptar e/ou verificar o MAC a conexão é imediatamente encerrada (sem revelar *por que* isso ocorreu) e o protocolo de aperto-de-mão precisa ser feito de novo para reestabelecer a conexão. Isso é para bloquear *qualquer* tipo de ataque, e como no TLS uma chave nova é criada a cada conexão, qualquer vantagem que o atacante tivesse no momento em que o protocolo falhou deverá ser anulada.

Como você pode aplicar isso ao seu caso, não vou arriscar a opinar. Criptografia é um assunto muito complexo ([como mencionado por EduardoFernandes em sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64614/215)), e eu ainda não tenho conhecimento suficiente para propor algo que depois não se descubra ter uma falha horrorosa... Do topo da minha cabeça, a opção que eu exploraria seria no momento da autenticação (os dispositivos se autenticam mutuamente, certo?) eles combinarem em um identificador de sessão (único, gerado aleatoriamente pelo participante com mais recursos - provavelmente o servidor) e um contador, e cada mensagem incluir na geração do seu MAC esses dois valores. Como duas mensagens jamais repetirão os dois valores ao mesmo tempo (na mesma sessão, contadores crescentes; em sessões diferentes, IDs distintos) um ataque de *replay* não será possível.

Ainda precisaria pensar um bocado sobre o assunto (teria como o adversário interferir *no momento em que esse ID da sessão é negociado*? hmmm...) mas no momento é tudo que eu tenho pra contribuir.